# Function runs fine the first time, but second time it produces 2 windows as opposed to just one

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The purpose of this code is to accept text from a form, pass it on to a function and thow this text inside a background worker that will execute a second function. This background worker has its do_work and work_completed event listeners defined. The problem is when I run this code for the first time the application is running, it works fine. The next time I execute "fetchFunction" and subsequently the fetchStuff function, I get 2 windows or 2 objfrmMChild showing instead of 1 like the first time I ran it.

I ran my code in debug mode and saw that the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runs once and pops the window up, but then it circles back a second time and runs again. Any idea why?

```
     public void fetchFunction(TextBox text)
     {
        fetch.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        if (!fetch.IsBusy)
        {
            Lists.BGWParams bgwp = new Lists.BGWParams();
            bgwp.Value = text.Text.Trim();
            fetchStuff(bgwp);
        }

        else
        {
            fetch.CancelAsync();
        }
    }


    private void fetchStuff(Lists.BGWParams parameters)
    {
        DoWorkEventHandler dweh = (object senderA, DoWorkEventArgs argsA) =>
        {
            if (argsA != null && argsA.Argument is Lists.BGWParams)
            {
                Lists.BGWParams p = argsA.Argument as Lists.BGWParams;
                p.Result2 = genericClass.fetchOtherStuff_DoWork(p.Value);            
                argsA.Result = argsA.Argument;
            }
        };

        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler rwceh = (object senderB, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs argsB) =>
        {
            if (argsB != null && argsB.Result is Lists.BGWParams)
            {
                Lists.BGWParams p = argsB.Result as Lists.BGWParams;
                frmMChild objfrmMChild = new frmMChild(this);

                countResults = p.Result2;
                objfrmMChild.MdiParent = this;
                objfrmMChild.Show();
                objfrmMChild.populateDataGridwithStuff(p.Result2, p.Value);
            }
        };

        fetch.DoWork += dweh;
        fetch.RunWorkerCompleted += rwceh;

        fetch.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetchStuff` is referencing a `BackgroundWorker` that is an instance field.  Each time you're calling `fetchStuff` you're adding *yet another* handler for each of those events.  The first time there's one, the second time there's two, the third time there's three.  You're doing the work that many times, and displaying the result that many times.

Just make the BGW local to that method.  If you create a new BGW each time you won't have that problem.  If you do this you still need to support cancellation though.  The easiest way to do that is to create a `CancellationTokenSource` as a field that the BGW uses.  Create a new CTS each time you start the operation.  (That said, you never check for cancellation in your `DoWork` handlers, so you're not actually cancelling anything currently.)

The alternative is to attach these event handlers when creating this class, rather than inside of `fetchStuff`; have `fetchStuff` just call `RunWorkerAsync`.  (Or for that matter just omit it entirely and have whatever calls it call `RunWorkeAsync`.)

Comment: Could you provide me with some code so I could see what that looks like?

Comment: @user2216791 I'm confident in your ability to take these explanations and translate them into the (very minor) code changes necessary to get your application to work, and that by doing so yourself you'll have a much greater understanding of how your own application works.